# Adding realtime database to my app on android studio - Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0

Tags: android, firebase

i've been working with firebase to access an activity on my project. Everything works fine, no compilation errors. However after i go to tools > firebase i can connect to my app easily, however when i try to click Add Real time database it shows me this:

```
build.gradle will include these new dependencies:
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

Since compile is deprecated i use implementation, and when i do

> Implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'

i get the following error Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0

and my sync fails.

Comment: turn off your gradle offline sync option and try again

Comment: Thanks for replying dude, but tell me how do i do that, and which firebase version should i use? 16.0.1:15.0.0 or the current one?

Comment: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1

Comment: go to settings->build and execution->gradle->uncheck offline work option and click ok.....

Comment: it was already unchecked, and also it didn't work. by setting it to implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1' it tells me to change to 16.0.1:15.0.0, again...

Comment: In Android Studio go to "Tools -> Android -> SDK manager". In the SDK manager select the tab "SDK Tools" and below "Support Repository" you find 'Google Repository', upgrade it if it's not using the latest version.

Comment: well its checked and says im using version 58

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `jcenter()` in your project-level gradle.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and keep remaining as @Tomin B said.

Comment: i already have it brother, both on allprojects and buildscript, let me explain again, i need to authenticate/add real time database, but i can't. it tells me to "Accept change", but if i accept the change nothing is changed and i receive log errors. Because otherwise, whenever i try to login it returns INVALID_PASSWORD and gives me auth errors on logcat

Comment: @PublioElon i think i didn't understood your problem, as per your above comment i understood that you are trying to add firebase database dependency in you android studio using firebase assistance. but i am not able to get where you are trying to login and what error log you are getting can post?

Comment: dude, i dont even know how to say it, i just feel like im illiterate, reason why it wasn't working was because when referring to the new intent, i misstyped the intent name and didnt notice, i spent 7 hours, trying to look up on the internet for mistakes, when it was all along, i feel so stupid...

Answer (score 1):

Change **Root Gradle** to

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        google() // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
```

And **App Gradle** To

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Hope This May Help You

Comment: i already have those settings from previous research, still nothing. This is how my gradle app is: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1 'implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1' implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1' as for dependencies on classpath... classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'